# php login verification

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am now at my wits end. here's what i want to know, how can i check the information provided by a user on my login page (consisting of only username and login) against that which i have in my database? i can already manage to do that but now my problem is 2 things that i have identified. 1) if the information provided is true when compared against that which is stored in my database then i want to direct the user to a different page (i assume the ACTION method in my HTML will take care of that). but if the input is wrong then i want an iteration of the login page so they can re-enter their details.

```
if ($p===$p1)
{
    header("Location:success.php");
}
else
{
    header("Location:fail.php");
}
```

above is my code with $p being the value from the password field on the form and $p1 being the value from the database. what now happens with this code is that even if the passwords and even the usernames do not match, the user can still access member pages. i have been able to identify that the problem lies with the "header" method. but even if i swap the two around the user is still directed to success.php. if you don't understand the crux of my question please i implore you do not ignore it just ask me and i'll provide more information. sorry but i can't seem to be able to get the

Comment: What's the output when you `echo` `$p` and `$p1`? Are they actually text? Are they equal? Also: I read in your question that `$p1` is the password from the database begin compared to what the user enters - this is BAD! Storing passwords unencrypted (which you must when directly comparing to user inputs) is a security issue. Why not restructure it so that you're getting the user record from the database based on the user id and password. If you get a record, the login was successful.

Comment: yeah i do get a record and i first use SQL to get the data from the database before i compare so in the end i'm comparing variables, my problem was with the "header" and the triple "="

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you propose here does not prevent the user from accessing the 'member' pages - however it should determine which page the user is sent to after submitting a password. If the latter is not the case then there's something going wrong elsewhere in the code.

But as I mentioned, if you want to prevent unauthenticated users from accessing some pages, then the simplest solution is to set a flag in the session at authentication, e.g.

```
session_start();

if ($_POST['password']===stored_password($_POST['username'])) {
    $_SESSION['authenticated']=$_POST['username'];
    header("Location:success.php");
    exit; 
} else {
    header("Location:fail.php");
    exit;
}
```

Then at the top of each and every authenticated page:

```
session_start();
if (!$_SESSION['authenticated']) {
    header("Location:fail.php");
    exit;
}
```

(note the explicit exit after the header('Location:...');)

Once you've got this licked then you can start thinking about regenerating the session id at authentication to prevent session fixation / hijacking issues, and storing the users password as a hash to prevent disclosure issues.

Comment: thanks, this one also works but i'm met with an error on my browser that reads **Fatal error: Call to undefined function stored_password() in C:\websites\MySite\logincheck.php** when i add your second code to my authenticated page, but without that last bit of code i do get directed to the next page

Comment: the function "stored_password()" is no default php function. I assume symcbean mean that you should create a function that returns the user password by reference of the username.

Comment: okay so if i exclude the "stored_password()" function then it all works fine, however my problem now is that when i add your second code block to the top of the page that you go to if login is successful, then the user gets sent to fail.php. so i'm going out on a limb and assuming that the 'if' condition has a problem since everything works without it... is there a way to fix this? please help

Comment: oh sorry it was human error (my lack of extensive php experience.. lol) thanks a ton @Nyxxos and you too symcbean and everyone else for everything

Answer (score 4):

> what now happens with this code is that even if the passwords and even
>   the usernames do not match, the user can still access member pages

you need to learn the basics about sessions.

a few links links to help you build your first authentication page:

[PHP Login script tutorial](http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/6.html)
[Php Simple Login Tutorial](http://www.knowledgesutra.com/discuss/tlddl-php-simple-login-tutorial-learn-simple-login.html)
[Create Database Login Page with PHP](http://www.pctalknet.com/php/login.php)

Answer (score 3):

you use this if to check if the elements are the same

```
if ($p===$p1) {
```

you say $p is your post variables and $p1 is the data from the database...

I'm not very sure because i dont see much of your script but i would expect that the if question is always true because you use three = chars "===" with three equal signs you check the variable type.

Both Variables are from the type "array" (as far as i expect) so your question always looks like this

```
if (array === array) {
```

and this is always true.

You should specify your if question.

```
if ($p['password'] == $p['password']) {
```

or whatever you want to check.

Summary: As far as i can see in your short code i would expect that the Problem are the tripple equal signs

EDIT:

you should change your login. 
The best way is to check via sql if the user informations are right.

Example:
$sql = "SELECT id FROM user WHERE name='" . $p['name'] . "' and password = MD5($p['password'])"

and then execute the sql. You could also use a count(*) to check if the login infos are correct. If its not correct there should be no return from the database.

Comment: The === operator compares the values of the variables as well, not just the type. i.e. 1 === 2 would return false

Comment: yeah that just occured me.. well as long as it works but Mr_Chimp is right. The === operator compares the  value and the type

Comment: i'm using phpMyAdmin to check what's in the database coz i'm a bit reluctant to use SQL code just to check my database since i'm new to php and that is where my focus is at currently. i have no problem with SQL statements, i've used MS SQL Server and SQL through Java so that's not a weak element with me. if it's not much of a bother can you look at symcbean's answer or more specifically the error i posted as a comment on his answer that is being generated by my browser. i'll only be able to check back tomorrow though... please you guys are a lot of help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var_dump($p);
var_dump($p1);
```

It won't solve your problem but it will show you what is stored in the variables and what type of variable they are.

What values are you expecting?